# Formula/code to average variable number of rows in one column depend on Criteria

Tags: vba, formula, average

I have data that looks like this.

```
142 2.506

144 2.677

146 2.258

148 0.398

150 0.108

152 3.257

154 0.855

148 2.515

150 2.671

152 2.3

154 0.412

156 3.253

158 0.855

148 2.488

150 2.676

152 2.279

154 0.376

156 0.125

158 3.277

160 0.858

146 2.496

148 2.693

150 2.264

152 0.402

154 0.122

156 3.256

158 0.877

142 2.495

144 2.661

146 2.274

148 0.382

150 0.133

152 3.258

154 0.838

147 2.491
```

I want to compute the average of that right column rows which has left column values 142, 144, 146, 148, 150, 152, 154 (increasing).

When the value drops to 148, compute another average of 148, 150, 152, 154, 156, 158 and so on.

Please help me if you can. I will greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far or are you just looking for the answer?

Answer (score 0):

So the numbers always start at 142, and increment by 2 to 154?  So you need a loop that will repeat 7 times.

```
dim rowCount, x as integer
dim average as double
rowCount = 2

Do until cells(rowcount,1).value = ""
for x = 1 to 7
average = average + cells(rowcount,2).value
rowcount = rowcount + 1
next x
cells(rowcount,3).value = average/7
rowcount = rowcount + 1
loop
```

If it always increments by 7, use a for loop to count to 7.

Comment: Thank you Acantud! It does not always increment by seven. It can vary from 4 to 8. Also, it could start from any number. I was able to use your code as a starting point to get what I want. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Dim rowCount, x, n As Integer
Dim average As Double
rowCount = 2
Do Until Cells(rowCount, 1).Value = ""
n = 1
average = Cells(rowCount, 2).Value
Do While Cells(rowCount, 1).Value < Cells(rowCount + 1, 1).Value

If Cells(rowCount, 1).Value = "" Then End
average = average + Cells(rowCount + 1, 2).Value
rowCount = rowCount + 1
n = n + 1
Loop
Cells(rowCount, 3).Value = average / n
rowCount = rowCount + 1
Loop

Comment: Great news, I see what you did, hope it keeps going well- Edit- quick tip, to make your code more readable, just put four spaces in front of it.